# Unable to turn on bluetooth ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10, bluetooth

After upgrade to 13.10 my bluetooth stoped to work:
- I don't see bluetooth indicator at all
- I am not able to turn it on and serch for devices

I've already checked some fixes like
- instaled fixed a bazaar fork indicator-bluetooth 
- added my user to bluetooth group

Below are some outputs that show my config / issues

```
$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    2.732391] usb 5-2: Product: Bluetooth V2.0 Dongle
[    2.732394] usb 5-2: Manufacturer: Bluetooth v2.0
[    2.758748] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    2.758786] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.758797] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.758800] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.758805] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.178551] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.178556] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.178567] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    8.210172] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    8.210187] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    8.210189] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

** list of usb devices

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04f2:0833 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c018 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

** installed bluetooth packages

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i blue
ii  blueman                                         1.23+update1-2ubuntu1                      amd64        Graphical bluetooth manager
ii  bluewho                                         0.1-1                                      all          notifies new discovered bluetooth devices
ii  bluez                                           4.101-0ubuntu8b1                           amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-compat                                    4.101-0ubuntu8b1                           amd64        BlueZ 3.x compatibility binaries
ii  bluez-cups                                      4.101-0ubuntu8b1                           amd64        Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
ii  bluez-hcidump                                   2.5-1                                      amd64        Analyses Bluetooth HCI packets
ii  bluez-tools                                     0.1.38+git662e-3                           amd64        Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux
ii  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0                       3.8.1-2ubuntu2                             amd64        Introspection data for GnomeBluetooth
ii  gnome-bluetooth                                 3.8.1-2ubuntu2                             amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools
ii  indicator-bluetooth                             0.0.6daily13.02.19-0ubuntu1                amd64        System bluetooth indicator.
ii  libbluetooth3:amd64                             4.101-0ubuntu8b1                           amd64        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  libgnome-bluetooth-dev                          3.8.1-2ubuntu2                             amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools - support library development files
ii  libgnome-bluetooth11                            3.8.1-2ubuntu2                             amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools - support library
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                     1:4.0-0ubuntu6                             amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  python-bluez                                    0.18-2                                     amd64        Python wrappers around BlueZ for rapid bluetooth development
```

** not able to set it as UP

```
$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1B:10:00:11:DC  ACL MTU: 1017:8  SCO MTU: 64:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:457 acl:0 sco:0 events:16 errors:0
    TX bytes:68 acl:0 sco:0 commands:16 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8d 0xfe 0x9b 0xf9 0x00 0x80
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 


$ sudo hciconfig hci0 up
Can't init device hci0: Operation not supported (95)

$ hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device

$ rfkill list 
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

** loaded modules:

```
$ lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69070  0 
bnep                   19564  2 
binfmt_misc            17468  1 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
vesafb                 13828  1 
btusb                  28267  0 
bluetooth             371874  12 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
nvidia              10675220  49 
coretemp               13435  0 
kvm_intel             138538  0 
kvm                   431315  1 kvm_intel
hid_generic            12548  0 
gpio_ich               13476  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
usbhid                 53014  0 
hid                   101512  2 hid_generic,usbhid
microcode              23518  0 
lpc_ich                21080  0 
serio_raw              13413  0 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    51465  1 
snd_hda_intel          48171  3 
parport_pc             32701  1 
snd_hda_codec         188738  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
mac_hid                13205  0 
snd_pcm               102033  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
drm                   296739  2 nvidia
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30095  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29433  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69141  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_h    da_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
soundcore              12680  1 snd
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42299  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
floppy                 69370  0 
r8169                  67341  0 
mii                    13934  1 r8169


$ ps axu | grep -i blue | grep -v grep
root       723  0.0  0.0  19264  1720 ?        Ss   16:10   0:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
myuser    1571  0.0  0.1 448968  5604 ?        Sl   16:10   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-bluetooth/indicator-bluetooth-service
```

** /etc/bluetooth/main.conf without comments:

```
$ grep -v '#'  /etc/bluetooth/main.conf | grep .
[General]
Name = %h-%d
Class = 0x000100
DiscoverableTimeout = 0
PairableTimeout = 0
PageTimeout = 8192
AutoConnectTimeout = 60
InitiallyPowered = true
RememberPowered = true
ReverseServiceDiscovery = true
NameResolving = true
DebugKeys = false
EnableGatt = false
```

All advices will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is described as [Bug 60824](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60824) in Bugzilla.

You will find a patch in this thread:
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=107379

This patch is not yet available in official Ubuntu releases.

In order to get the dongle work before it is made official, you have to rebuild the Ubuntu kernel.

Here is an How To:

---

- Save the patch in ~/Patch_Bluetooth.txt
- Get the sources of the Ubuntu kernel (the ones of saucy version i.e. 13.10)

  ```
  cd ~
  git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-saucy.git
  ```
- Apply the patch to the kernel sources

  ```
  cd ~/ubuntu-saucy
  patch -p1 < ~/Patch_Bluetooth.txt
  ```
- If you never built a Kernel before, install the following tools.

  ```
  sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)
  ```
- It is now time to launch the kernel compilation.

  ```
  cd ~/ubuntu-saucy
  fakeroot debian/rules clean
  fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
  ```

  At the end of this process, you should have produced some .deb file in ~/ directory.
- Use the new kernel for boot.

  ```
  cd ~
  sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.11.0-19*.deb linux-image-extra-3.11.0-19-generic_3.11.0-19.33_amd64.deb
  ```
- Restart your computer.

You should now see the bluetooth indicator and detect bluetooth devices.

---

Answer (score -1):

I have exactly the same problem (same dongle, same Ubuntu version, same configuration files, same command outputs ...).

The only information concerning this dongle compatibility is from ubuntu wiki :

> Works out-of-the-box in Ubuntu v10.04 ~ 11.04 Stopped working reliably in 11.10, frequent kernel panics and other general not good stuff, [Bug: 901770]
>
> $ lsusb Bus 007 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
>
> $ hciconfig -a hci0 Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
>
> Might need same fix as Belkin : **add `blacklist hci_usb` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, and add `hci_usb reset=1` to /etc/modules**

I tried the "Belkin fix" with no success, but maybe it will work for your dongle on Ubuntu 13.10.